# L1 regularisation not working for linear regression

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, linear-regression

L1 regularisation not working for linear regression, here in below example I have created a data as y =  2*x1 + 5*x2 + 3*x3 + 5

Here in dataset x4 parmeter is there, but to calculate the output in sample data, we are not using it, so when we apply L1 regularisation, we should get w4 near to zero, but still it is not working. Anything missing here ?

```
# In[1]:


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# In[2]:


def plot_the_data(training_df, output):
  plt.xlabel("feature")
  plt.ylabel("label")
  plt.ylim([output.min() - 1 , output.max() + 1])
  print(training_df.columns)
  for column in training_df.columns:
    print(training_df[column].shape)
    plt.xlabel(column)
    plt.scatter(training_df[column], output)
    plt.show()

total_data = 10000
output_label = 'output'
normalize_data = True
def createData(total_data):
  my_label = np.zeros((total_data,))
  my_feature = np.append(np.random.uniform(low=10, high=100, size=(total_data,)).reshape((total_data, 1)), # first col
                       np.random.uniform(low=300, high=500, size=(total_data,)).reshape((total_data, 1)), axis=1)  # sec col
  my_feature = np.append(my_feature , 
                       np.random.uniform(low=600, high=800, size=(total_data,)).reshape((total_data, 1)), axis=1)  # third col
  my_feature = np.append(my_feature , 
                       np.random.uniform(low=900, high=1000, size=(total_data,)).reshape((total_data, 1)), axis=1)  # fourth col, unused

  for i, row in enumerate(my_feature):
    my_label[i] = ((2 +  np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.1) ) * row[0]) + ((5 + np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.1) )* row[1]) + ((3 + np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.1) )* row[2]) + (50 + np.random.randint(low=1, high=3))

  training_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x1' : my_feature[:,0], 'x2' : my_feature[:,1], 'x3' : my_feature[:,2], 'x4' : my_feature[:,3], 'output': my_label})
  return training_df 


training_df = createData(total_data)
training_df = training_df.reindex(np.random.permutation(training_df.index))
training_df[output_label] = training_df[output_label] / 1000
print(training_df)
plot_the_data(training_df, training_df[output_label])


# In[3]:


def normalize_the_data(training_df):
  normalized_df = pd.DataFrame()
  norm_list = {}
  for column in training_df.columns:
    print(f"Max, Min of {column} pre normalization: {np.max(training_df[column]):0.2f}, {np.min(training_df[column]):0.2f}")
    norm_l = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
    norm_l.adapt(training_df[column])  # learns mean, variance
    Xn = norm_l(training_df[column])
    normalized_df[column] = Xn.numpy()[0]
    norm_list[column] = norm_l
    print(f"Max, Min of {column} post normalization: {np.max(normalized_df[column]):0.2f}, {np.min(normalized_df[column]):0.2f}")
  return normalized_df, norm_list

def normalize_the_test_data(training_df, norm_list):
  normalized_df = pd.DataFrame()
  for column in training_df.columns:
    print(f"Max, Min of {column} pre normalization: {np.max(training_df[column]):0.2f}, {np.min(training_df[column]):0.2f}")
    norm_l = norm_list[column]
    norm_l.adapt(training_df[column])  # learns mean, variance
    Xn = norm_l(training_df[column])
    normalized_df[column] = Xn.numpy()[0]
    print(f"Max, Min of {column} post normalization: {np.max(normalized_df[column]):0.2f}, {np.min(normalized_df[column]):0.2f}")
  return normalized_df
    
if normalize_data == True:
  print("Data Normalization enabled")
  norm_l = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
  normalized_df, norm_l = normalize_the_data(training_df)
else:
  print("Data Normalization disabled")
  normalized_df = training_df


# In[4]:


normalized_df = normalized_df.loc[:, normalized_df.columns != output_label]


# In[5]:


tf.random.set_seed(1)
learning_rate=0.01
my_learning_rate = learning_rate
epochs=20
batch_size=20
validation_split = 0.2
print(normalized_df.head())
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(training_df.shape[1] - 1,), kernel_regularizer='l2'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=my_learning_rate),
                loss="mean_squared_error",
                metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(),tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])    
model.summary()
weights_dict = {}
weight_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: weights_dict.update({epoch: { "w" : model.get_weights()[0][0][0], "b" : model.get_weights()[1][0]}}))

history = model.fit(x=normalized_df,
                      y=training_df[output_label],
                      # verbose='0',
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      epochs=epochs,
                      callbacks=weight_callback,
                      validation_split=validation_split)

# Gather the trained model's weight and bias.
trained_weight = model.get_weights()[0]
trained_bias = model.get_weights()[1]
epochs = history.epoch  
hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
rmse = hist["root_mean_squared_error"]
testrmse = hist["val_root_mean_squared_error"]  
print("Defined build_model and train_model", trained_weight, trained_bias)


# In[6]:


predictions = model.predict(normalized_df)
print(training_df.loc[:, training_df.columns == output_label])
plot_the_data( training_df.loc[:, training_df.columns == output_label],  predictions.T)


# In[7]:


def plot_the_data_and_pred(training_df, output, pred):
  plt.xlabel("feature")
  plt.ylabel("label")
  print(training_df.columns)
  for column in training_df.columns:
    plt.xlabel(column)
    plt.scatter(training_df[column], output)
    plt.scatter(training_df[column], pred)
    plt.show()

plot_the_data_and_pred(training_df, training_df[output_label], predictions)


# In[8]:


def plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, rmse, testrmse):
  """Plot the loss curve, which shows loss vs. epoch."""
  plt.figure()
  plt.xlabel("Epoch")
  plt.ylabel("Root Mean Squared Error")
  plt.plot(epochs, rmse, label="Training Loss")
  plt.plot(epochs, testrmse, label="Validation Loss")
  # plt.plot(epochs, rmse, label="Loss")
  plt.legend()
  #y axis limit for the y axes
  plt.ylim([rmse.min()*0.97, rmse.max() + 10])
  plt.show()
    
plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, rmse, testrmse)


# In[9]:


output_label = 'output'
total_test_data = 1000
my_test_label = np.zeros((total_test_data,))

def createTestData(total_data):
  my_label = np.zeros((total_data,))
  my_feature = np.append(np.random.uniform(low=50, high=60, size=(total_data,)).reshape((total_data, 1)), # first col
                       np.random.uniform(low=350, high=400, size=(total_data,)).reshape((total_data, 1)), axis=1)  # sec col
  my_feature = np.append(my_feature , 
                       np.random.uniform(low=690, high=750, size=(total_data,)).reshape((total_data, 1)), axis=1)  # third col
  my_feature = np.append(my_feature , 
                       np.random.uniform(low=950, high=975, size=(total_data,)).reshape((total_data, 1)), axis=1)  # fourth col, unused

  for i, row in enumerate(my_feature):
    my_label[i] = ((2 +  np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.1) ) * row[0]) + ((5 + np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.1) )* row[1]) + ((3 + np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.1) )* row[2]) + (50 + np.random.randint(low=1, high=3))

  training_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x1' : my_feature[:,0], 'x2' : my_feature[:,1], 'x3' : my_feature[:,2], 'x4' : my_feature[:,3], 'output': my_label})
  return training_df 


test_df = createTestData(total_test_data)
test_df[output_label] = test_df[output_label] / 1000
print(test_df)
# plot_the_data(test_df, test_df[output_label])

if normalize_data == True:
  print("Data Normalization enabled")
  normalised_test_df = normalize_the_test_data(test_df, norm_l)
else:
  print("Data Normalization disabled")
  normalised_test_df = test_df


normalised_test_df = normalised_test_df.loc[:, normalised_test_df.columns != output_label]
print(normalised_test_df)
test_predictions = model.predict(normalised_test_df)
plot_the_data( test_df.loc[:, test_df.columns != output_label], test_df[output_label])

plot_the_data_and_pred(test_df.loc[:, test_df.columns != output_label], test_df[output_label], test_predictions)


# In[10]:


print("Defined build_model and train_model", trained_weight, trained_bias)


# In[11]:


results = model.evaluate(normalised_test_df, test_df[output_label], batch_size=batch_size)


# In[12]:


tf.random.set_seed(1)
epochs = 20
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(training_df.shape[1] - 1,), kernel_regularizer='l1'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=my_learning_rate),
                loss="mean_squared_error",
              
                metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(),tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])    
model.summary()
weights_dict = {}
weight_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: weights_dict.update({epoch: { "w" : model.get_weights()[0][0][0], "b" : model.get_weights()[1][0]}}))

history = model.fit(x=normalized_df,
                      y=training_df[output_label],
                      # verbose='0',
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      epochs=epochs,
                      callbacks=weight_callback,
                      validation_split=validation_split)

# Gather the trained model's weight and bias.
trained_weight = model.get_weights()[0]
trained_bias = model.get_weights()[1]
epochs = history.epoch  
hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
rmse = hist["root_mean_squared_error"]
testrmse = hist["val_root_mean_squared_error"]  
print("Defined build_model and train_model", trained_weight, trained_bias)


# In[13]:


results = model.evaluate(normalised_test_df, test_df[output_label], batch_size=batch_size)


# In[ ]:
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks such that you are normalizing the training data, but it's not clear if the test data is normalized in the same way. Be sure to do that pls.

When applying L1 regularization, the regularization term should be added to the loss function during model compilation. Try this:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=my_learning_rate),loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError() + tf.keras.regularizers.L1(0.01), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(), tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
model.summary()
```

It would help a lot if you could share some toy data so I can replicate this.